# How to auto-save Avro schema in Confluent Schema Registry from Apache NiFi flow?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

How to auto-save Avro schema in Confluent Schema Registry from Apache NiFi flow?

That's basically the question.
I am not finding the way of automatically storing the Avro schema of the record in the Confluent Schema Registry from a NiFi flow. It is possible to flexibly read and populate message with the reference to the schema in the Confluent Schema-Registry, but there should be a way of auto-creating one in the registry instead of demanding Confluent Schema-Registry to be initialized upfront before NiFi flow starts.

**Update**
Here is my current Flow:

[image: NiFi Flow]

I'm reading from a Postgres table using `QueryDatabaseTableRecord` processor (version 1.10) and publishing [new] records to a Kafka topic using `PublishKafkaRecord_2_0` (version 1.10.0).

I want to publish to Kafka in Avro format storing (and passing around) the Avro schema in the Confluent Schema Registry (that works well in other places of my NiFi setup).

For that, I am using `AvroRecordSetWriter` in the "Record Writer" property on the `QueryDatabaseTableRecord` processor with the following properties:

[image]

PublishKafkaRecord processor is configured to read Avro schema from the input message (using the Confluent schema registry, the schema is not embedded into each FlowFile) and uses same `AvroRecordSetWriter` as `QueryDatabaseTableRecord` processor to write to Kafka.

That's basically it.

Trying to replace the first `AvroRecordSetWriter` with one that embeds the schema with the hope that the second `AvroRecordSetWriter` could auto generate schema in the Confluent Schema Registry on publish, since I don't want to bloat each message with my embedded Avro schema.

**Update**
I've tried to follow the advice from the comment as follows

[image]

With that I was trying to make first access to the Confluent Schema Registry the last step in the chain. Unfortunately, my attempts were unsuccessful. The only option that worked was my initial described in this question that required a schema in the registry upfront/in advance to work.
Both other cases that I tried ended up with the exception:

```
org.apache.nifi.schema.access.SchemaNotFoundException: Cannot write Confluent Schema Registry Reference because the Schema Identifier is not known
```

Please note, that I cannot use "Inherit Schema from record" in the last writer's schema access, since I'm getting an invalid combination and the NiFi config validation doesn't pass such combination through.

Comment: Hello, are you able to solve that? I am facing the same problem now.